# Non-US shipping when selling on ebay.com?

Tags: ebay

I am living in Hong Kong and signed up for an ebay account. The account works on ebay.com as well as ebay.com.hk. Unfortunately I do not speak Chinese and therefore cannot use ebay.com.hk since there does not seem to be an english option for the page.

So when using ebay.com, I am trying to sell an item and only offer local (= Hong Kong) shipping. However, ebay always adds "United States" to the shipping options. I also cannot find it in the list of exclusions.

Is there any way for someone not living in the USA to place a sell auction in ebay.com that does not ship to the USA?

Comment: While I can't answer your question, I have a tip: You could try using Chrome's built-in translator to use ebay.com.hk